# failed to open stream : Is a directory in

Tags: php, file-upload, warnings

I am getting the following warnings on trying on move an uploaded file from the temp folder to the desired one using php

Warning: move_uploaded_file(test/) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/..../filename.php on line 69

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpKrCpQw' to 'test/' in /home/..../filename.php on line 69

following are line nos 67 and 69 that are giving the error :

```
$destination = "test/". $name;

$answer = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'],$destination);
```

Comment: `$destination` is apparently `'test/'`. `$name` obviously is empty.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems like your name is null

```
$destination = "test/". $name;
```

echo you name and see what is coimg there.

Comment: I'm getting this error but my filename is perfectly constructed and the folder has permissions... :(

Comment: @NickBedford Error shows only if there is `no write permission` or the `path is not proper`.

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was the filesize.

So, check php.ini to see if the uploaded file exceeds `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.

Or maybe add a validation rule in Laravel or js.

Comment: Same here, with Laravel 5.6.