# file_put_contents(...): failed to open stream: Is a directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have fuction for upload image in base64:

```
public function upload(UploadImageRequest $request) {
    $data = (\Request::input('image'));

    $decode = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data));
    $info = @getimagesizefromstring($decode);
    $extn = image_type_to_extension($info[2]);
    if ($extn ==".png"){
        $fullName = md5(time().uniqid()).$extn;
        Storage::disk('public')->put('images/',$fullName, $decode);

        $image = Image::make();

        $image->url = Storage::url($fullName);
        $image->saveOrFail();

        return Response::json($image, ResponseHttp::HTTP_CREATED);
    }

    else {dd(1);}
}
```

I try to save my image to public/image/ directory, but failed.

ERROR:

```
    (1/1) ErrorException
file_put_contents(/home/artem/PhpstormProjects/thefeedfeed-api/storage/app/public/images): failed to open stream: Is a directory
```

Comment: I think permission issue in your directory!! Can you please show your exact error

Comment: update post and add error

Comment: *update post and add error* - @katedega but it is your question? :O

Comment: @Script47 - i have error which I write in post. What i do wrong? Or how save file to directory which I need?

Comment: @katedega Please check  this =>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560658/failed-to-open-stream-is-a-directory-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('images/',$fullName, $decode);
```

should be

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('images/'.$fullName, $decode);
```

You're providing three arguments - the directory, the file name and the contents. This method should take two arguments, the full file path (i.e. directory and file name), and the contents. You need to concatenate the first two arguments - just change `,` to `.`